# Replace elements in an array (python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array:

```
y=['a','s','d','a','f','d','g']
```

I want to replace all elements of this array by integers.
I thought that a simple solution would be to do the following:

```
c = np.unique(y)
```

and then replace all elements in y with their index in c.
I can possibly do elementwise comparisons like this:

```
for n, i in enumerate(c):
    for m, j in enumerate(y):
        if i == j:
            y[m] = n
```

output:

```
 y=[0, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3]
```

but is there a numpy function to do this in a compact way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y = [c.tolist().index(i) for i in y]
```

Comment: Just use `return_inverse=True` as an argument to `np.unique`.

Comment: Hey @JanChristophTerasa that sounds nice. Thanks :)